# How to change the column size dynamically based on the text length in Crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I need to change the column size dynamically based on the text length in Crystal report. Any help much appreciable ..!! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `Can Grow` option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution..!!
We can change the column size dynamically based on the text length by a formula.It should be use in TextObject's formatting formula section. There we can see "Width Adjustment" section.

If Length(CurrentFieldValue) > 12 then
 2000;

2000 decides the width of your TextObject/Column size. As per your context you can change the value accordingly.